# How to use an array for the Constraints in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to use a constraint definition in Pyomo inside a for loop. 
The following example is a simplification of my problem

```
for i in range(5):
    model.C[i] = Constraint(expr = model.x[i]<=10)
```

This haven't worked so far, since I couldn't find a way to declare model.C as an array and keep it as part of the model.
I could see some examples using the rule attribute; however, I wonder if I can make this work without it.
Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. You must create a `ConstraintList` and use the `add()` method:

```
model.C = pyo.ConstraintList()
for g in dados_ger.index:
   model.C.add(expr= (Pg[g]<=dados_ger.maximo[g]))
```